# Error while installing Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost from NuGet

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to get this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api running.

Therefore I need to put this into NuGet package manager console

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost

I got the following Error

> Install-Package : Das angegebene Argument liegt außerhalb des gültigen Wertebereichs. (in english: The given argument is out of the valid value range.)
>   parametername: supportedFrameworks
>   at line:1 position:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

You can find this package's dependencies on https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost/5.2.3 .

I continued to locate where the error comes from and found that the Newtonsoft Json package could be the problem. But since there are no dependencies or subpackages given, I cannot go any further which let me post my question here:
What to do, to solve this problem?

My project's target framework is .NET 4.5.1 and I use VS2013 with recent update and NuGet manager V2.8 (also the recent version for VS2013, I think).

**Edit1:** I found that e.g. my Microsoft.CSharp reference is to Microsoft.CSharp V4.0.0.0 ... for recent Json versions Microsoft.CSharp V4.0.1 or higher is needed. How do I update this? And why do I have to do this?

Comment: did you try using manage Nugate package ?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "manage" ?

Comment: right click on your project references and select manage nuget packages in that select owin pakage to install